# OpenERP 7: Set Default Value of Group By

Tags: odoo

I'm grouping POLine by Order Reference by Manual , it filtering the data as shown in below image.

```
<record id="view_purchase_line_search" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">purchase.order.line.search</field>
        <field name="model">purchase.order.line</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Search Purchase Order">
                <field name="order_id"/>
                <field name="partner_id" string="Supplier" filter_domain="[('partner_id', 'child_of', self)]"/>                  
                <group expand="1" string="Group By...">
                <filter icon="terp-gtk-jump-to-rtl" string="Order Reference" domain="[]" context="{'group_by' :'order_id'}"/>
                <filter string="Supplier" icon="terp-partner" domain="[]" context="{'group_by' : 'partner_id'}" />                    
                </group>
            </search>
        </field>
</record>

<record id="view_purchase_line_list" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">purchase.order.line.tree</field>
        <field name="model">purchase.order.line</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Purchase Order Lines" create="false">                    
                <field name="order_id"/>
                <field name="partner_id" string="Supplier" />
                <field name="product_id"/>
                <field name="price_unit"/>
                <field name="product_qty"/>
                 <field name="product_uom" groups="product.group_uom"/>
                <field name="price_subtotal"/>
                <field name="date_planned"  widget="date" width="135"/>
                <field name="state" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="invoiced" invisible="1"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
</record>                   


<record id="action_purchase_line_list" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">PO Tree Structure</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">purchase.order.line</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_purchase_line_list"/>
    <field name="context">{'search_default_order_id':1 }</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_purchase_line_search"/>  
</record> 

<menuitem action="action_purchase_line_list" id="menu_purchase_list"
        parent="menu_procurement_management"
        sequence="0"/>
```

But i need this filter by default (i.e) when openning this window at first time it should groupped the data

[image]

Tried Below Code:

```
<field name="context">{'search_default_order_id':1 }</field>
```

[image]

I need "Order Reference" instead of **Order Reference POOOO1** in search field.
 Any Advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
update your code with this.

<filter name="groupby_order" icon="terp-gtk-jump-to-rtl" string="Order Reference" 
domain="[]" context="{'group_by' :'order_id'}"/>  

and pass <field name="context">{'search_default_groupby_order': 1}</field> in 
act_window. Hope this will be useful to you.
```

Answer (score 2):

try this, In your **purchase_view.xml** file search this id **view_purchase_order_filter** and than add below filter in  Group By...

```
<filter icon="terp-gtk-jump-to-rtl" name="order_id" string="Order Reference" domain="[]" context="{'group_by' :'name'}"/>
```

Than find this id **purchase_form_action** and paste below context

```
<field name="context">{'search_default_order_id': 1}</field>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Your code perfectly works for PO but i'm requesting for POLine. Could you please check my updated post.

Comment: It Works <filter icon="terp-gtk-jump-to-rtl" name="order_id" string="Order Reference" domain="[]" context="{'group_by' :'order_id'}"/>